# Work with git on Windows 7 machine

Tags: linux, git, windows-7, ubuntu

I have a Windows 7 machine, and I want to install git on it in order to do Rails development.

I've heard that it's better to work with git on Linux, so I installed Ubuntu. The problem with Ubuntu is that I have to restart the computer each time I want to switch between Windows and Linux.

Is that possible to run Ubuntu as Windows application (like any other program) ?

Could you recomend any other options ?

I want it to be installed on the hard drive rather than USB stick or something else.

Comment: Why not try msysgit with a decent Git GUI client on Windows?

Comment: I agree with Mike, I'm using git on a Windows 7 machine without any problems. If you really persist, you could look into virtualizing your Ubuntu in Windows 7. [VMWare, Virtual Box, ...](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeline_of_virtualization_development) all could do the job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes its possible. You can install Ubuntu on a virtual machine such as Vmware Workstation or Paralels Desktop or VirtualBox(free). The you can use it almost like an application. Or use [msygit](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/)

Answer (score 4):

msysgit on Windows is the  standard for using Git on Windows, and now, it is almost as good as running git on Linux. For the learning phase, especially if you are moving from SVN and TortoiseSVN, use TortoiseGit. But git is best used ( and enjoyed!) from the command line. So try to use the command line and understand the git concepts.

Comment: Regarding *git is best used ( and enjoyed!) from the command line*: you haven't used a **decent** Git GUI so far.

Comment: @MikeL. - Point me towards one please

Answer (score 3):

Well, TortoiseGit has been working fine for me. It's a native Windows application, adding Git features to the Windows Explorer's context menu: https://tortoisegit.org/

Apart from the Windows app (if you want to keep running your 'nux stuff), VirtualBox offers something called the "seamless mode" which enables you to use programs running on your virtual machine kind of seamlessly on your native desktop without the hassle of the other OS around it.